# How to loop through text boxes and verify if there are duplicate values?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to setup a function that sends a mail to a defined list of recipients. 
Each recipient is fetched from a textbox. The problem is that I want to identify if there are any duplicate values and exclude them when sending the email.

As an example, if textbox1 has the same value as textbox2, don't include textbox1 value in the recipients list.

I've tried with the following sub

```
Private Sub CheckDuplicates()
        Dim x As Long
        Dim y As Long
        Dim User() As TextBox = {Mail_user1, Mail_user2, Mail_user3, Mail_user4, Mail_user5, Mail_user6, Mail_user7, Mail_user8, Mail_user9, Mail_user10, Mail_user11, Mail_user12, Mail_user13, Mail_user14, Mail_user15, Mail_user16, Mail_user17, Mail_user18, Mail_user19, Mail_user20, Mail_user21, Mail_user22, Mail_user23, Mail_user24, Mail_user25, Mail_user26, Mail_user27, Mail_user28, Mail_user29, Mail_user30}

        For x = 1 To 30 - 1
            For y = x + 1 To 30
                If User(x).Text = User(y).Text Then
                    User(y).Text = ""
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```

The issue is that I get the following error when I want to send the mail:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

And the mail sub looks like this:

```
Public Function AddRecipients(mail As outlook.MailItem) As Boolean
        Dim retValue As Boolean = False
        Dim recipients As outlook.Recipients = Nothing
        Dim recipientTo As outlook.Recipient = Nothing
        Dim recipientCC As outlook.Recipient = Nothing
        Dim recipientBCC As outlook.Recipient = Nothing

        Try
            recipients = mail.Recipients
            ' check if there are any recipients and remove them
            While recipients.Count > 0
                recipients.Remove(1)
            End While
            ' new recipients list

            CheckDuplicates()

            '------------------CC section---------------------------
            recipientCC = recipients.Add("someemail@test.com")
            recipientCC.Type = outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC

            'hidden recipients section
            ' recipientBCC = recipients.Add("")
            ' recipientBCC.Type = outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC
            retValue = recipients.ResolveAll()
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(recipientBCC) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipientBCC)
            If Not IsNothing(recipientCC) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipientCC)
            If Not IsNothing(recipientTo) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipientTo)
            If Not IsNothing(recipients) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipients)
        End Try
        Return retValue
    End Function

    Private Sub MailTime()
        Dim OTmail As outlook.MailItem
        Dim AppOutlook As New outlook.Application
        Try
            OTmail = AppOutlook.CreateItem(outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
            'add users from AddRecipients
            AddRecipients(OTmail)
            OTmail.Subject = "Test OT mail"

            OTmail.Body = "Test Ot mail"
            OTmail.BodyFormat = outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            OTmail.Display()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Could not send, resolve the errors !")
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            OTmail = Nothing
            AppOutlook = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: How about putting them all into a list and using `Distinct` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will loop through all the TextBoxes and get a Distinct list for you.

```
Private Function uniqueRecipients() As List(Of String)

    Dim recipients As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    For Each ctrl As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        recipients.Add(ctrl.Text)
    Next

    Return recipients.Distinct.ToList

End Function

Private Sub Button26_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button26.Click

    Try

        Dim myRecips As List(Of String) = uniqueRecipients()
        Dim oneLine As String = Strings.Join(myRecips.Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray(), ";")
        'send mail

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: The Try sequence is sending the mail individually to each user found in the list? (To be more specific, i am trying to send one mail to a bulk list of distinct users)

Comment: Updated to generate a single delimited line.

Answer (score 1):

Use right <s>tool</s> type for the job - `HashSet(Of String)`, [Enumerable.ToHashSet Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netframework-4.8)

```
Private Function GenerateMailRecipientsFrom(textboxes As IEnumerable(Of TextBox)) As String
    Dim uniqueRecipients = textboxes.
        Select(Function(textbox) textbox.Text).
        Where(Function(text) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) = False).
        ToHashSet()

    Return String.Join(";", uniqueRecipients)
End Function
```

`HashSet` accepts only unique values.

Then use a collection of all textboxes on the form

```
Dim mailTo As String = GenerateMailRecipientsFrom(Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox))
```

When you have predefined collection of textboxes you can still use the same method

```
Dim userMailTextBoxes As textBox() = { Mail_user1, Mail_user2, .. }
Dim mailTo As String = GenerateMailRecipientsFrom(userMailTextBoxes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice one ! @Fabrio thanks for the code and explanation. As a side note, I have tried to load the unique values into a listbox and then insert them into outlook email while using this method:

```
 Dim x As Long
            For x = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
                If ListBox1.Items.Item(x) <> "" Then
                    recipientTo = recipients.Add(ListBox1.Items.Item(x))
                    recipientTo.Type = outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo
                End If
            Next
```

Worked like a charm :)